# How can I definitely and permanently increase the open file limit in Ubuntu

Tags: bash, ulimit, parallels

I recently used `parallel` and got this message:

> parallel: Warning: Only enough file handles to run 252 jobs in parallel.
> parallel: Warning: Try running 'parallel -j0 -N 252 --pipe parallel -j0'
> parallel: Warning: or increasing 'ulimit -n' (try: ulimit -n ulimit -Hn)
> parallel: Warning: or increasing 'nofile' in /etc/security/limits.conf
> parallel: Warning: or increasing /proc/sys/fs/file-max

As per message I tried:

```
ulimit -n `ulimit -Hn`
```

which by the way I have no idea what does it do.

But I still get that message. Then I saw [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/730129/does-parallel-limit-cause-some-items-to-not-be-checked) and it has nothing new in it. Then I checked [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/610130/how-to-set-ulimit-value-permanently) and added these lines of codes to the `/etc/security/limits.conf`:

```
*               soft    nofile          65535
*               hard    nofile          65535
```

And  I again see that warning.

Then I tried to `grep -nr ulimit` in `/etc` and in `/home` directory to see if another limit overrides those values, and I saw no number related to `soft/hard nofile`.

I have no idea why it does not work.

Is there a definite and permanent way to remove that limit or increase it?

How can I debug to see why it's not applied?

Comment: You cannot remove the existence of the limit, as all computers have a maximum capacity. That said, this limit is sometimes enforced by the system if the hardware is physically incapable of supporting the configured value. For example, if you were to change the number from 65535 to 1000000, then you would need a remarkable amount of RAM and local storage. So, with this in mind, could you [edit] your question to include your hardware specifications? This will make it much easier to offer some values that your system may not override.

Comment: @matigo thank you for mentioning the hardware. I don't want a large number. Even 1024 would suffice. The problem is not hardware here. It's just that whatever I do (even after rebooting) the `parallel` keeps nagging about that limit.

Comment: From your question. which by the way I have no idea what does it do. Why would you ever run a command that you do not know what it does?

Comment: @David, I do have a test PC for these tasks.

Comment: How many file handles per job do you need? When the jobs are running what do you get for `lsof | wc -l` and `sudo sysctl fs.file-nr`?

Comment: @DougSmythies, basically even 1024 would be enough for me. The problem is that this annoying warning does not go away. And since a lot of our internal scripts are made using `parallel`, any internal command that we run we should see that annoying warning.